# Estimates of the sum involving both the Mobius function and Mertens function.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I want to ask on the estimates of the sum
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)M\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{x^s}{s\zeta(s)^2}ds.$$
But it is little known to the sign-changes of the Mertens function. Additionally, the sum can be represented as
$$ \sum_{1 \leq n \leq x}\bigg( \sum_{n=ab}\mu(a)\mu(b) \bigg). $$
It is easy to find the condition that $(the \  inner \  sum)=0$ if every degree of the prime factors of $n$ is bigger than $1$, where $k(n)$ is the square-free kernel of an integer. But also the representation has some difficulties.

So I thought that it is more good to deal with the integral, then there have to be some informations on the integrations with the integrand $\zeta(s)^{-2}$. I want to ask the estimates of the sum or the informations on the integrals with the integrand $\zeta(s)^{-2}$.

Comment: of course, it is $\mathcal{O}(x^{\sigma_0+\epsilon})$ where $\sigma_0$ is the abscissa of convergence of $\sum_n \mu_n n^{-s}$ and the Riemann hypothesis is $\sigma_0 = 1/2$. you should understand how the dominating pole of a Dirichlet series $\sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ determinates the growth rate of $A(x) = \sum_{n \le x} a_n$. substract to $a_n$ a sequence $b_n$  capable of eliminating that pole (without adding a new one with greater real part), and you'll get that $A(x) \sim B(x)$